# Strncpy gives unwanted characters at end of string

Tags: c, string, struct, linked-list

Basically, my program uses linked lists to give commands to a robot. I'm using `strcpy()` to copy commands into my linked list node struct, but it adds unwanted characters to the end (i.e. "`right`" turns into "`right\000-º\rd`"). I've used `strncpy()` and tried to allocate memory, all to no avail. In my struct, the cmd used is of size `10`, as in when I initialized the struct, I made a `cmd[10]` inside, as I know that the command will never exceed that size.

```
Node *newNode(char cmd[10], int val) {

   Node *newnode = NULL;
   newnode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

   if(cmd == "handup" ||cmd == "handdown" ||cmd == "colour" ||cmd == "forward" ||cmd == "backward" ||cmd == "right" ||cmd == "left")
   {
     strcpy(newnode->cmd, cmd);
     newnode->val = val;
     newnode->next = NULL;
     return newnode;
   }

   else
   {
     printf("Invalid command.\n");
     return NULL;
   }

}
```

I need it to give me a result of "right" or "forward" etc., but it keeps adding weird stuff to the end of string and I don't know what to do

Comment: Are you checking the string from your debugger? Everything after the `\0` isn't part of the string.

Comment: `"I've used strncpy and tried to allocate memory"` - strncpy does not allocate memory. Neither does strcpy.  Show the declaration of your `struct Node` thing so we can see what's in it.

Comment: Bare in mind that `cmd == "handup"` is not comparing strings but pointers. You have to use `strcmp()`. I don't see where you are using `strncpy()`, I see `strcpy()`.

Comment: @Mance Rayder The if statements works properly, it’s only when initializing the string into the newnode that it messes up

Comment: `printf()` should be outside the function. You should check that `malloc()` actually allocates the memory you asked for.

Comment: @tkausl the string in my debugger shows me that cmd = “right”, but the string in newnode has a bunch of unwanted characters in the end, which is what im trying to fix

Comment: No, the `if` statement doesn't work properly. The condition you're testing is always false, because you're comparing pointer values, and the address of an object will never be equal to the address of a string literal.

Comment: @Keith Thompson In gdb the if statement works fine every time, except for if an incorrect command is being entered. The cmd being passed into the function is a user entered command, a char of size 10. The issue for me stems from trying to insert the command given by the user into the Node

Comment: On second thought, it's possible that the `==` comparisons will appear to indicate that the strings are equal, but only if the `cmd` argument is a string literal *and* your compiler shares memory for identical string literals. At best, you're counting on something that will break if you use a different compiler or use something other than string literals.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, the cmd argument is a string literal. But I just can't figure out how to fix the fact that I get random characters afterwards, because I have a function that prints the commands in the nodes, and they come out as "right\000-º\rd", etc, instead of "right" or "forward"

Comment: @KinkyLlama @KeithThompson, if the `if`s are working, there may be an issue somewhere else. Is it to late to ask for a MVE? I don't want to be pedantic (;-)) but compile with `gcc -Wall` and tell me that you don't get `warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]`

Comment: @ManceRayder: It's never too late to ask for a [mcve].

Comment: @KinkyLlama: You say you have a function that prints `"right\000-º\rd"`. You haven't shown us that function.

Comment: @KinkyLlama: Please see the update to my answer (1st paragraph).

Comment: @KeithThompson Although apparently it was too early as there were no close-votes for lacking a MRE (until me)

Answer (score 3):

**IMPORTANT NOTE** This answer covers only *some* of the problems with your code. The biggest problem is that you haven't shown us a complete program. We don't know what your type `Node` looks like, and we don't know what function you're using that prints `"right\000-º\rd"`.

Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update your question.

Why are those characters unwanted? Why does it matter?

A *string* is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". If you have a `char[10]` array object containing

```
{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', '?', '$', '\xff', '!' }
```

then that array contains a string of length 5, `"hello"`.

`strcpy` copies strings, and it simply ignores any bytes past the terminating null character that are not part of the string. `strncpy` is similar, but it's not quite a string function, and it can be dangerous if you're not very careful; see [this article of mine](https://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html) for more information.

For most applications, you can simply ignore everything past the terminating `'\0'` character. Every string function will ignore that data, since it's not part of the string.

If you have a reason to care about what's after the `'\0'` character (part of the array, but not part of the string), you can set it to `'\0'`. The simplest way is to use `memset` to set those bytes to zero.

Some more observations about your code:

```
Node *newNode(char cmd[10], int val) {
```

Your parameter `cmd` is of type `char*`, not `char[10]`. It's a pointer parameter, not an array parameter (C doesn't have array parameters).

```
if(cmd == "handup" ...
```

This is a pointer comparison, not a string comparison (pointed out by Mance Rayder's comment). The pointers are likely to be unequal. Use `strcmp` to compare strings. (Taking a closer look, if `cmd` was passed as a string literal, and **if** your compiler shared space for identical string literals, then `==` might be true. We haven't seen your entire program, so it's difficult to be sure.)

For example, this:

```
if ("hello" == "hello") puts("equal"); else puts("unequal");
```

can print either `equal` or `unequal`.

Your `Node` type is probably a structure containing a `char*` member `cmd`. You don't allocate memory for the string that `newnode->cmd` will point to.

Recommended reading: Sections 6 and 8 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). (And the rest of it.)

Comment: The reason is I need to use the string later on in a different function and when I check, for example, if newnode->cmd == “right”, it doesn’t work, since they’re different strings

Comment: @KinkyLlama: The reason for what? If your `Node` contains `char*` members that point to strings, you'll need to `malloc` memory both for the `Node` object *and* for the strings.